# LINQ query with a generic table

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I'm tryng to have only one select in my method. That method will select a table based in a defined string and execute a select.

```
private static void Load()
{
    DataClassesDataContext contexto = new DataClassesDataContext();
    IQueryable newTable = null;

    string tabela = "A";

    switch (tabela)
    {

        case "A":
            newTable = contexto.GetTable<Table2>();
            break;
        case "B":
            newTable = contexto.GetTable<Table1>();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    var genericQuery = from a in newTable
                       select a;
}
```

What can I do to have genericQuery with the right table values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work unless you genericize the Load method:

```
private static void Load<T>()
{
   ...
   var genericQuery = contexto.GetTable<T>();
   ...
}
```

Comment: I can´t call Load in that way, I only know the type of T inside the switch statement!

Comment: What are you trying to do with genericQuery? I don't understand what problem you're hitting.

Comment: I need to have the result of a selected table based in the value of the string tabela.
I don't know the selected table before call Load method.

Comment: What do you mean "have the result of a selected table"? You have that in newTable variable. What code problem are you hitting?

Comment: @JudahHimango - My db context doesn't have GetTable method at all. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: @Davor, make sure you have the proper using statements. (System.Data.Entities, or something)